# How to use both ORDER BY and IN together in a query in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I use Cassandra 3.0.5.

I'm having problem using `ORDER BY` and `IN` together.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE my_status.user_status_updates (
    username text,
    id timeuuid,
    body text,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id)) 
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Query:

```
SELECT username, id, UNIXTIMESTAMPOF(id), body
FROM user_status_updates
WHERE username IN ('carol', 'dave')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the partition key; you must either remove the ORDER BY or the IN and sort client side, or disable paging for this query"

I'm sure I've seen people query this without errors, so I know there is a way to get around this. What do I need to do to make this query work, or is it inefficient to query both `ORDER BY` and `IN` together?

Comment: how does the schema look?

Comment: Since you're only asking for 2 rows returned, removing the `ORDER BY` clause seems in the query, and doing the sorting client-side, seems like a quick workaround.

Comment: having this issue with that exact query from the book "Learning Apache Cassandra Second Edition". no mentions in the book about any errors or having to turn paging off.  I have submitted this issue to the errata on packt publishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using both IN and ORDER BY will require turning off paging with the `PAGING OFF` command in cqlsh.
`cqlsh> PAGING OFF` is the answer.

Comment: Every time when I create a session in Java, the paging is on. So is there a way to set paging off permanently?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that. I decided not to use this method after all.

Comment: @user2782405 while creating Cluster Object in java set QueryOptions as Cluster.builder().setQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(500));

Comment: Thank you @RishikesanVaradharajan

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765097/8356801) why is you need to turn off paging when using both IN and ORDER BY in the same query.

Comment: @tet how to disable it in Datastax DevCenter?

Comment: @Shyam I don't know. I guess you need to create a new question with a Datastax tag.

Answer (score 4):

You've set the Clustering Key to be ordered ASC, but are requesting it be ordered DESC in your query.  These are at odds and are counter-productive.  If you change the Clustering Key to DESC, then you won't need the ORDER BY clause in the query.  If you truly do need to have the Clustering Key be ASC for other queries, then I would suggest a second table with it being DESC.  Design your tables for what the query will require.  Hope that helps.

Adam