# Cassandra query compatibility when migrating from 2.1 to 3.x

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I am migrating my data from cassandra 2.1 to 3.x.

I have this below `cassandra` query which runs fine in my `cassandra 2.1' but gave error on 'cassandra 3.x'

**Query**: `"select * from event_users where app_id =1234 and event_name='login' and date in('2017-06-11', '2017-06-11')order by username desc limit 10";`

**Cassandra v2.1 : Works fine**

**Cassandra v3.x : Error** 
`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the partition key; you must either remove the ORDER BY or the IN and sort client side, or disable paging for this query"`

As error says not to use IN and OrderBy at the same time and use sorting at the client side.

Sorting and then selecting top 10 rows won't be feasible at the client side.

**Table Schema** : `CREATE TABLE event_users ( app_id bigint, event_name text, date text, username text, count counter, unique_count counter, PRIMARY KEY ((app_id, event_name, date), username) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (username ASC)`

What is a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Both cassandra version should give you error. I have tested it on `2.1.14` and `3.10`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use both ORDER BY and IN together in a query in Cassandra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168306/how-to-use-both-order-by-and-in-together-in-a-query-in-cassandra)

Comment: Using both IN and ORDER BY will require turning off paging with the PAGING OFF command in cqlsh. cqlsh> PAGING OFF is the answer.

Comment: Will `paging off `will have any performance impact, and what does default `paging on` does

Comment: If turned paging off,query result will provided in a single request. By default paging is on, result is provided page by page. default row in a single page is 100