# how to use in and order by at the same time in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I see the official document: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useColumnsSort.html

can use "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID IN (102,104) ORDER BY age ASC;"

how to define the users table or materialized view?

PAGING OFF is a must?

Here is my current view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW navigation_by_id_time AS
       SELECT * FROM navigation
       WHERE competition_id IS NOT NULL AND event_type_id IS NOT NULL AND event_id IS NOT NULL AND market_id IS NOT NULL AND market_start_time IS NOT NULL AND market_suspend_time IS NOT NULL
       PRIMARY KEY (event_type_id, market_start_time, event_id, market_id, market_suspend_time);
```

This query doesn't work

```
select * from navigation_by_id_time where event_type_id in(1,2,3) order by market_start_time;
```

message="Cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the partition key; you must either remove the ORDER BY or the IN and sort client side, or disable paging for this query"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra does not support paging when bth IN and ORDER BY are used. It is stated also in datastax documentation - [Retrieval using IN keyword](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryIN.html).

Also, if you inspect the [code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/207c80c1fd63dfbd8ca7e615ec8002ee8983c5d6/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/statements/SelectStatement.java#L393), you will also get some more explanations.

The check was added in [JIRA-6722](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6722) and the explanations of the behaviour is:

> It is however not all that easy in practice. If you query a full page
>   of each partition and there is many partitions in the IN, you'll load
>   tons of data in memory, defeating in large parts the goal of paging.
>   If you instead query less than the page size of each partition, you
>   now may need to re-query some of the partitions depending on what the
>   merge sort yield on those first pages.

As a conclusion: you need to turn off [paging](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshPaging.html) in cqlsh. If you are using a Java client, [this](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/) might help (also explains some more stuff).